# xcode 5.1.1 complaining: ISO C++11 does not allow access declarations

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, xcode4, xcode5

I have a project that builds and runs fine on Xcode 4.6.3. 
But it does not on Xcode 5.1.1.

This is the unique error I get, hundred times.

"ISO C++11 does not allow access declarations; use using declarations instead".

Basically it wants me to go from:

> ```
> typedef Something<MType>::Index Index;    
> Something<MType>::N;
> ```

to

> ```
> typedef Something<MType>::Index Index;    
> using Something<MType>::N;
> ```

Why is it?

If I "solve it" as Xcode says, the final app behaves randomly.

Is it possible to build this project on Xcode 5.1.1 as if it were 4.6.3? (in other words: changing the project settings, but keeping the code intact)

AFAIS, the C++ flags have the same value for both Xcode versions.
C Language Dialect = GNU99 [-std=gnu99]
C++ Language Dialect = GNU++11 [-std=gnu++11]
C++ standard library = libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a deliberate change to the compiler:

http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=183882

The standards body says: "Access declarations were deprecated in the 1998 standard and have no benefits over using-declarations. They should be removed in C++0x."

And I can't find anyway of reverting to an older (non-standard compliant) C++11 behaviour.  I was half expecting this to work:

clang -std=c++0x

But, it doesn't. You get the same error.

Including using looks like the right fix. I've just done some testing here and it does what it says on the tin.

Probably not what you want to hear, but I think you should look into why the code behaves randomly when you use the using directive.

Comment: +1, especially for "*I think you should look into why the code behaves randomly when you use the using directive.*"